# Display Spend and DistinctCount of Brand permanently in the Tree-map of Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have data like below:

```
Country, Advertiser, Brand, Spend
C1, A1, B1, 10
C1, A1, B2, 5
C1, A2, B3, 0
C1, A2, B4, 20
C2, A1, B1, 8
C2, A1, B5, 7
C2, A2, B6, 4
C2, A2, B3, 3
C2, A2, B7, 2
C2, A3, B8, 9
```

There, the distinct count of brand by country is as follow:

```
C1 => 4
C2 => 6
```

and total spend by country is as follow:

```
C1 => 35 
C2 => 33
```

I created a tree map to visualize 'Spend and BrandDistinctCount by Country and by Advertiser as follow:

[image: My current Tree-map with tooltip when mouse is hovered]

As you can see, the tooltip shows the 'Spend' and 'DistinctBrandCount' **when mouse is hovered over the area**. What I'd like is more of a **permanent display (for all blocks in the Tree-map) of 'Spend' and "DistinctBrandCount'** in the Tree-map. Is there a way to customize the look of Tree-map in Power BI desktop and if so, how do I accomplish that?

Thank you in advanced for your answers/suggestions!

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible with the built-in visual. You'd probably have to build your own custom visual to do this.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Thank you for the follow-up. What would be a good resource to learn how to build custom visuals in Power BI?

Comment: That's not something I've done myself yet, so I'd probably start with the [info on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Visuals).